# An argument between lovers

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there an expression to refer to an argument / word fight between lovers (or any two people who are an item, whether married or single)? I'm thinking about those arguments that arise from small things and seem to raise hell for a few hours, or a few days, and end up vanishing into thin air because they were really about something silly or insignificant (or, more likely, because of some insecurity blowing insignificant matters into ungodly proportions).

Something in the sense of: They couldn't live apart for five seconds, constantly declaring their undying love, and yet every other week there they were in the throes of yet another 'lover's argument'.

Comment: *lovers' quarrel* is the most common term for this.

Comment: Some just call that "generating an excuse for make-up nookie..." ;-)

Comment: Spat is often used in this context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about **lover's squabble**?

From Dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster:

> [**squabble**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/squabble?s=t): a
> petty quarrel
>
> [**squabble**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squabble): a noisy altercation or quarrel usually over petty matters

**NOTE** on @k1eran's answer:

Interestingly, Dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster define **tiff** as follows:

> [**tiff**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tiff?s=t): a slight or
> petty quarrel
>
> [**tiff**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tiff): a small fight or argument about something that is not important

So, according to Dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster, **squabble** and **tiff** mean more or less the same thing.

Turning to Oxford Dictionaries, one finds the following:

> [**squabble**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/squabble):
> a noisy quarrel about something trivial
>
> [**tiff**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tiff?s=t): a petty
> quarrel, especially one between friends or lovers
>
> [**lovers' tiff**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lovers%27_tiff):
> a trivial or short-lived dispute between lovers (as noted by @k1earan)

I wonder why the definition of **tiff** in Oxford Dictionaries references friends/lovers while the definitions in Dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster do not.

Comment: As suggested by @deadrat, a *lovers' spat* conveys the same meaning. According to Dictionary.com, a *spat* is a petty quarrel. *Lovers' quarrel* also works, but lacks the explicit reference to *petty*.

Comment: I was really divided. I ended up choosing yours because you listed the definitions for several possibilities.

Answer (score 6):

**lovers' tiff**

> (also lover's tiff)
>   NOUN
>   A trivial or short-lived dispute between lovers.
>   — [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lovers'_tiff)

**EDIT** I ran the ngram using options from other answer and comments and as deadrat commented *lovers' quarrel* is the most used, those of course they don't all mean exactly the same thing.

Also for simplicity, and on principle, I ignored ones with *lover's* not *lovers'*.

[image]

Comment: Also *lovers' quarrel* (more popular) and *lover's spat* (less popular). For what it's worth, I think *tiff* conveys the ephemeral and unseriousness the best.